# MongoDB replication topograph and majority write for a two data centre setup

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have a fairly low concurrency application which is latency sensitive where the data has to be written across two data centers.

The database will have four physical hosts for redundancy; a primary and secondary in the main "A" data centre and a pair of hot standby hosts in the secondary "B" data centre. Call them AP, AS, BP, BS.

We want automated failover between AP and AS in the main data centre but manual promotion of hosts in the secondary data centre if we have to swap data centres.

We have additional hardware to run an arbitrator node in each data centre to ensure that master election is based on three hosts within a given data centre. The arbitrator in the B data centre will be offline. As we don't want the B side hosts to be promoted without manual intervention we can set their priority to zero.

We would like to achieve safe writes from java clients running in the A data centre that are confirmed to be on three of the four nodes: AP, AS, and BP.

Is a vanilla four node setup okay? If we loose the A data centre, servers BS and BP might not both be up to the same read. If we turn on the B side arbitrator, and increase the priorities on the B side to prefer BP as master can we expect BS and BP come up date with the latest reads?

Or to get data into AP, AS and BP should we setup a three data node replica set of AP, AS and BP that the clients will write to with a "w=3" error check and somehow chain BS off the back of BP? [edit: No specifying w=3 is dangerous when nodes are taken down for maintenance or if connectivity to the B side is lost.]

Comment: why would you need to check anything before "manual" promotion - won't the delay be long enough for BS to catch up off of BP on its own?  Are you okay with your writes failing if one of your designated nodes is down for maintenance?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky i have edited the question to make it clear that BS and BP getting up to date is the crux of my question when they get disconnected from the A side master.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky thanks for pointing out the risk of writes blocking if we set w=3 and take a nodes down for maintenance or they go down. Thinking it through it also means that if we lost the B side then things would no longer write on the A side until we brought up a third host in the primary. So clearly a majority write is better. Sounds like we should have AP,AS,BP,BS all up and set a 'majority' write which would ensure writes to three hosts (so data safe in the second data centre) but if we lost connectivity to B data centre things would still write (ensuring on both AS and AP hosts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a replica set the primary is selected via an election.  This election follows certain rules and nodes have certain requirements in order to be "electable".

One of those requirements is that they *must* be most up-to-date to be elected as a primary.

What this means in your case is that if BP has some write that BS does not have, then BS cannot be elected as a primary.  BP would have to be elected as the primary and BS will be syncing off of it (and will eventually catch up and get that write).

In reality, since you will be doing a fail-over manually, it's not really possible to end up in a scenario where BS doesn't have all the write BP has because while you are logging in and getting new arbiter set up BS will get all the writes from BP that it didn't have (because a secondary does not have to sync off of the primary, it can sync off of another secondary that is ahead of it).

Comment: Would a majority write on the four node setup ensure correct working if we lost the B side? i.e. would be a three node write whilst B was available but automatically become a two node write if one or both the B side server disconnected from the master?

Comment: no, majority refers to the _configured_ replica set.  So if 4 are configured, then majority is always 3.  I assume you actually don't mean 4 but rather 5 including the arbiter?

Comment: yes i was counting data holding servers not arbiters but we would have the A side arbiter up to be able to fail over to AS if we lost AP automatically. that would make it it 5 nodes with a majority write of 3 which would have to be a write to a B side host. I found this informative blog which demonstrates your point that BP and BS will sync off one another when the lose connectivity to the A side :http://www.richardfawcett.net/2012/12/17/investigating-how-mongodbs-majority-write-concern-works/

Comment: does this approach work with gridfs in addition to regular usage of mongodb?

Comment: Sure, it's just a collection, basically